# Why suppress PHP errors?

Tags: php, error-handling

I was wondering why you would “suppress” a PHP error. I obviously see the difference in the extra warning line that the error produces, but is it good to suppress it?

```
 Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

vs

```
Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost'       (using password: YES) in (deleted) on line 8
Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

If so, should I get into the habit of typing `@` at the start of my MySQL queries in my PHP programs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should positively **NOT** get into the habit of suppressing errors.  The errors are there for a reason.  Instead, handle them properly and defensively in your code, and keep refining your code until the errors are gone.

You should do things like:

```
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

// Always test to see if your action/connection/whatever was successful
if (!$conn) {
  // something went wrong.  handle the error
  // Display a message for the user, write a message to `error_log()`, whatever's appropriate
}
else mysql_select_db($dbname);
```

On a production system, you should never display errors, since it risks giving up details of your code and database.  Instead, turn `display_errors` off in php.ini, or at runtime:

```
// In development and production, make sure all errors are reported
error_reporting(E_ALL & E_STRICT);

// In development show all errors on screen so you handle them as they occur
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// In production turn them off
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
```

In fact, error suppression with `@` is the second most voted for PHP bad practice [in this classic question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891301/top-bad-practices-in-php?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: +1: One caveat: These error messages should be suppressed from the *user*; broadcasting information about the internals of your code is not a good security feature.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth certainly.  I'm adding a bit about `display_errors`

Comment: oh dear, it appears you beat me to the punch.  excellent answer, michael.

Comment: Wow! thank you for the details. I learned a lot. However I do have some follow up questions... but first...  should I add them here in your comment or should I post it in the "answer your question" textbox?

Comment: @user672178 If you have followup questions, don't add them as an answer. If it's just a small 1 or 2, you can put them in comments, but it's often wise to edit your original question and append them there.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks for that. Actually, you've answered my question after I looked at your answer more closer. You went above and beyond my question and helped me learned a little more about PHP. Thank you again!