# radio button php mysql edit

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button

hello I would like to see (photo_edit.php) if it is 0 or 1 in radio button but I see no fields are empty

```
<td>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="visible" id="visible" value="1" /><?php echo (@$visible == '1') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>
        {widoczny} | 
        <input type="radio" name="visible" id="visible" value="0" /><?php echo (@$visible == '0') ? 'checked' : ''; ?>
        {niewidoczny}
    </p>
</td>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: watch out with `@` error suppression, it's not a very good practice, and a very bad habit. [see this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590619/suppressing-php-errors-why)

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
<input type="radio" name="visible" id="visible" value="1" 
<?php echo (@$visible == '1') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
```

You need to write the `checked option` within the radio button tag closed.You can also use

```
<?php echo (@$visible == '1') ? 'checked="checked"' : ''; ?>
```

Comment: Have you put within the input tag closed..??

Comment: http://mantykora.cleoni.com/~neo/ I do not understand here is my file would be grateful if you checked :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using  if conditions out of input fields boundaries `<input />`, use them within the input tags.

```
<td><p>
<input type="radio" name="visible" id="visible" value="1" <?php echo (@$visible == '1') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
{widoczny} | 
<input type="radio" name="visible" id="visible" value="0" <?php echo (@$visible == '0') ? 'checked' : ''; ?> />
{niewidoczny}</p>
</p></td>
```

Comment: I did and did not help

Comment: print this variable outside of input field @$visible and tell what value is coming, i think there is no value in it? also check with cmd+F5 or control + f5 on firefox