# Mysqli connection warning showing if connection details are bad

Tags: php

I have some code that allows a user to input details for their database on their server. After they submit the details, the code checks a connection to the database to see if valid details were entered. I want it to give outcomes of variables being true if the connection either works or does, like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($_POST['dbHost'],$_POST['dbUser'],$_POST['dbPassword'],$_POST['dbName']);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) { $badDetails = true; }
else { goodDetails = true; }
```

Problem is, if the details are indeed incorrect, it shows a PHP warning from the first line of the code above giving 'Unknown MySQL server host'.

What is the way around this? I don't want PHP throwing it's own visible error for this, I want to deal with the error myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not worry about visual errors. In a production environment, these should be turned off in the ini, and all errors should go to a log on the server instead of just to the screen.

This is configured with the [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) setting and [error_reporting()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Many frameworks override the PHP error handler with a custom implementation to display error in a pretty way, depending on their severity.
To achieve this, you can [override the PHP error handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)

[As seen in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) one can register custom handlers for regular errors and exceptions. And it is also possible to trigger an user defined error.

Comment: Ah right this makes sense! Thanks, I'll just make sure the erorrs are turned off when I put it all live.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a **`die()`**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($_POST['dbHost'],$_POST['dbUser'],$_POST['dbPassword'],$_POST['dbName']) or die("Database Connection Failed");
```

Comment: This seems logical but doesn't seem to be working for me. When for example the user puts in 'asd' for the database host, it throws the error:  Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [mysqli.mysqli]: (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host 'asd'

Answer (score 0):

A quick, dirty method would be error supression:

```
$con = @mysqli_connect( /* info */ );
```

Note that you should not keep this there, as this will suppress all errors, and mysqli can have multiple errors that you might need to know about.

Though I would check the host variable first, to see why the error is caused. You can also use die.

```
$con = mysqli_connect(/* info */) or die ("SQL Error!");
```

As far as where to look, try seeing that the host var is actually set and check it's value:

```
if (!isset($_POST['dbHost'])) {
    echo "Host var not set!";
} else {
    echo "Host var set: " . $_POST['dbHost']
}
```

Comment: `@` error suppression is a bad practice, especially for this type of error.

Comment: @NDM which is why I said it's a quick dirty solution :). It really can only be a bad practice if you don't handle the error, though for mysqli I suppose it's definitely a lot worse because of the numerous errors that can occur. I'll add a warning about it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I'm still stuck. I don't want to suppress all errors so your first option is a no go. Using die() doesn't seem to stop the warning showing if the database details are wrong either. As for your third bit of code, a string is definitely being input for the host as there's validation on the form where the user puts in database information.

Comment: Try printing it anyhow. Is the dbHost variable what you expected? If so, are you able to leave it here just to verify it would be correct overall?

Comment: Well for testing purposes I'm putting in the variable myself. So for example I'm purposely putting in a wrong host name of 'asd' which creates the PHP warning that I don't want to display.

Comment: Ah, I see. So you're just wanting to not have the error show up at all then. Look into `ini_set("displayerrors", 0);` and `error_reporting(0);` for hiding errors, as @NDM suggested.

Comment: @Rogue, the `@` error suppression not only [a **very** bad practice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590619/suppressing-php-errors-why), it is also bad for performance, and can lead to future bugs when other people start using the code and don't see any errors popping up. It should be handled by configuration wether errors are displayed or not.

Comment: I don't want to disable errors completely. I just don't want this particular warning to show so I can do an if statement saying 'if the connection doesn't work, display the form again on the page and ask the user to put the information in again'. How do I stop the warning in that way and create the variable I want?